# How can I implement a condition in the renderCell method of a MUI GridColDef component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the [Mui Grid component](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-col-def/#main-content) and want to render the content of one column based on some conditions of the data.

How can I basically implement a conditional in the `renderCell` method?

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [

      { field: 'offer_status',
          headerName: 'Status',
          flex: 1,
          width: 50,
          renderCell: (params) => ({
            if (params.value == 'is_sent')
                return <div>Sent</div>
          }
      )},
```

This doesn't work - I assume due to the syntax (unexpected token).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a working example of how to do a conditional inside a `renderCell`:

```
renderCell: params => {
  if (params.row.programId === 1) {
    return <div>Graduação</div>;
  }
  return <div>Pós-Graduação</div>;
}
```

This is a piece of code contained in one project that uses `ESLint` and `Prettier` code formatter.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I did a similar code to that you have shown in this post, after doing it, this error appeared:

> Expected to return a value at the end of method '`renderCell`'

This means that you **must** return some value to `renderCell` method, in your code if the conditional is **not satisfied** the `renderCell` will never receive a returned value and that's what causes the error. Also, another thing that you should do is write `params` instead of `(params)`, because it's a single function argument, this means that the parentheses around are not necessary.